$R^n$ and $R^{(I)}$ not isomorphic if $I$ is infinite
Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a free and finitely generated $R$-module. I have to show that there cannot be an isomorphism $M \cong R^{(I)}$ with $I$ infinite.
(To note: $R^{(I)} := \{(r_i)_{i \in I} | \forall i \in I: r_i \in R \wedge \{i | r_i ≠ 0\} \text{ is finite}\}$)
I know, as $M$ is free and finitely generated, there $\exists n \in \mathbb N$, such that $M \cong R^n$. So the problem is reduced to showing that $R^n \cong R^{(I)}$ is impossible if $I$ is infinite.
I think, intuitively, that a homomorphism $R^{(I)} \rightarrow R^n$ can not be injective, but I haven't found a concret reason why yet.

Hint: Show that $R^{(I)}$ is not finitely generated. More precisely, take an infinite basis, and show that if the module was finitely generated then this basis would have a finite generating subset. Why is that a contradiction?

As always you can also quotient modulo a maximal ideal to reduce to the notion of dimension of a vector space if that's more convenient.

@AnneBauval Does this post not require that the ring be commutative?

@AnneBauval Interesting, you answered a question, and then decided to close it.

@AnneBauval Actually, when I read the question, I thought OP meant commutative rings, but now I see it wasn't mentioned anywhere. So yeah, I think it should be reopened. And you can indeed add a few words to the answer (though it is already good enough IMO), just to remove any future doubts. Accepted answers can't be deleted, but can be edited.

You want to prove that if $M:=R^{(I)}=\oplus_{i\in I}R$ is finitely generated, then $I$ is finite.
Let $S\subseteq M$ be a finite set generating $M$. For each $s\in S,$ let $J_s\subseteq I$ be the set of indices $j\in I$ for which $s_j\ne0$. Then, $J:=\cup_{s\in S}J_s$ is finite, and equal to $I$ since
$\forall m\in M\quad\forall i\in I\setminus J\quad m_i=0$.
Note that contrarily to some previous posts about the rank of free modules (like 1, 2 or 3), this answer to that more specific problem doesn't need the ring $R$ to be commutative.
